# Saving the data to be shown later

Tags: ios, swift

I just added a catch and release button. I want to save the button output so that I can exit the app and reopen it with the saved button output. here's my code

```
import UIKit

class PokemonViewController: UIViewController {
    var url: String!
    var pokeCatch = false
    var currentPokemon: Int = 0
    var caughtPokemon: [Int] = []

    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var numberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var type1Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var type2Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var catchLabel: UIButton!
    
    
    func capitalize(text: String) -> String {
        return text.prefix(1).uppercased() + text.dropFirst()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        nameLabel.text = ""
        numberLabel.text = ""
        type1Label.text = ""
        type2Label.text = ""

        loadPokemon()
    }

    func loadPokemon() {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(PokemonResult.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.navigationItem.title = self.capitalize(text: result.name)
                    self.nameLabel.text = self.capitalize(text: result.name)
                    self.numberLabel.text = String(format: "#%03d", result.id)

                    for typeEntry in result.types {
                        if typeEntry.slot == 1 {
                            self.type1Label.text = typeEntry.type.name
                        }
                        else if typeEntry.slot == 2 {
                            self.type2Label.text = typeEntry.type.name
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    @IBAction func toggleCatch() {
        if pokeCatch == true{
            pokeCatch = false
            catchLabel.setTitle("Catch", for: .normal)
            caughtPokemon.append(currentPokemon)
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(caughtPokemon, forKey: "caughtPokemon")
        } else {
            pokeCatch = true
            catchLabel.setTitle("Release", for: .normal)
            if let index = caughtPokemon.firstIndex(of: currentPokemon) {
                caughtPokemon.remove(at: index)
            }
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(caughtPokemon, forKey: "caughtPokemon")
        }

}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "button output"?  What data do you actually want to save?

Comment: suppose if I tap the button it will show some output and when I reopen the stimulator I want the same output which I got by tapping the button @PhillipMills

Comment: Are you referring to the caughtPokemon?

Comment: What are you trying to save? `caughtPokemon`? The labels?

Comment: Pokédex keeps track of which Pokémon have been caught and which haven’t. if you stop running the app and then run it again, the Pokédex will forget which Pokémon are caught and which aren’t.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your requirement correctly. You need to be in the same toggle state that the user was when app was killed.
For that, you can save the pokeCatch boolean also to Userdefaults and set the state after app relaunch depending on that

```
@IBAction func toggleCatch() {
    if pokeCatch == true{
        pokeCatch = false
        catchLabel.setTitle("Catch", for: .normal)
        caughtPokemon.append(currentPokemon)
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(caughtPokemon, forKey: "caughtPokemon")
    } else {
        pokeCatch = true
        catchLabel.setTitle("Release", for: .normal)
        if let index = caughtPokemon.firstIndex(of: currentPokemon) {
            caughtPokemon.remove(at: index)
        }
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(caughtPokemon, forKey: "caughtPokemon")
    }
  // Save the current state to user default
  defaults.set(pokeCatch, forKey: "pokemonCatchState")
}
```

Then in viewWillAppear you can read the state and configure your UI accordingly.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    nameLabel.text = ""
    numberLabel.text = ""
    type1Label.text = ""
    type2Label.text = ""

    loadPokemon()

    // Restore Previous state
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    guard let pokeCatchState = defaults.bool(forKey: "pokemonCatchState") else {
      print("No State available, app may be starting for first time")
      return
    }
    if pokeCatchState {
      catchLabel.setTitle("Release", for: .normal)
    } else {
      catchLabel.setTitle("Catch", for: .normal)
    }
    // Restore caught Pokemon array
    if let caughtPokemonArray = defaults.value(forKey: "caughtPokemon") as [Int] {
      caughtPokemon = caughtPokemonArray
    }
}
```